# PHP while loop creates space between buttons

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to use a while loop to dynamically create buttons based on the number of `outcomeId`, but when I try to create the buttons with the loop, it creates gaps between the buttons.

```
<div class="outcomes">
        <?php
        //echo "<button class=\"outcomebtn\">Outcome A</button>";
        //echo "<button class=\"outcomebtn\">Outcome B</button>";
        $arrayLength = count($_SESSION['outcomeId']);
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $arrayLength){
            $num = $_SESSION['outcomeId'][$i];
            echo "<button class=\"outcomebtn\">Outcome $num</button>";
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

When I include the commented buttons, there are no gaps between any buttons. It only happens when I comment out the buttons that are not included in the loop.
Below is the webpage (1) including commented buttons (2) only using buttons from loop:

[image: (1)]

[image: (2)]

edit: here is my .css

```
.outcomes{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.outcomebtn{
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: rgba(10, 99, 231, 0.829);
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: 2px lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Probably won't fix anything but your parent div has spaces before and after the `=` for the class attribute. Also, could we see the **rendered** HTML as well as you CSS for these elements?

Comment: What happens if you have 4 values in `$_SESSION['outcomeId']`, so there will be 4 dynamic buttons.

Answer (score 2):

## Reproducing the problem

The problem reproduces only when there are exactly 2 buttons on the page:

```css
.outcomes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.outcomebtn {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: rgba(10, 99, 231, 0.829);
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: 2px lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outcomes">
  <button class="outcomebtn">Outcome 1</button>
  <button class="outcomebtn">Outcome 2</button>
</div>
```

## Reason

The problem happens because `.outcomes` class has fixed `height` in `200px`.

## Possible solution

One of the possible solutions is to get rid of this `height` css-property in `.outcomes` class at all:

```css
.outcomes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 100%;
}

.outcomebtn {
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: rgba(10, 99, 231, 0.829);
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: 2px lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="outcomes">
  <button class="outcomebtn">Outcome 1</button>
  <button class="outcomebtn">Outcome 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was that my CSS had an unnecessary height variable in the outcomes class. Once I removed that, it was fixed.